# Optimizing BufferedReader for large input in java

Tags: java, performance, buffer, bufferedreader, large-data-volumes

I am trying to read a single line which is about 2 million characters long from the standard input using the following code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
s = in.readLine();
```

For the aforementioned input, the `s = in.readLine();` line takes over 30 minutes to execute.

Is there a faster way of reading this input?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: What do you plan to do with the single line?  That is a huge String you would be creating.

Comment: @KingSweeney, may I ask you to accept the answer if you think it helps you and solves the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to read line by line but try to read a buffer of characters instead

Try something like this

```
BufferedInputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("your-file"));

    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;

    while ((count = in.read(data)) != -1) {
      // do what you want - save to other file, use a StringBuilder, it's your choice
    }
} catch (IOException ex1) {
  // Handle if something goes wrong
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
      try {
        in.close();
      } catch (IOException ) {
        // Handle if something goes wrong
      }
    }
}
```